# Node.js function scope - Azure Tables

Tags: node.js, azure-table-storage

so I have a code like this.

```
 var query = new storage.TableQuery().where('PartitionKey eq ?', req.body.RowKey._); 
storageClient.queryEntities(fieldtable, query, null, function (error, result, response) {


    var modelEntries = {};  
    var enumList = {};
    var enumName;
    modelEntries = result.entries;
    console.log(modelEntries);

    for (var i = 0; i < modelEntries.length; i++){

        if (result.entries[i].fielddatatype._ === "Enum"){
            enumName = result.entries[i].fieldname._;
            query = new storage.TableQuery().where('EnumName eq ?', enumName);

            storageClient.queryEntities(enumvalue, query, null, function (error, result, response) {
                enumList[enumName] = result.entries;
            });

        }

    }

    res.end(JSON.stringify(enumList));


});
```

My problem is with here.

```
storageClient.queryEntities(enumvalue, query, null, function (error, result, response) {
      enumList[enumName] = result.entries;
});
```

EnumList is receiving the data when I debug it. But once it is outside of the scope of the function it is empty. I think this is a function scope problem but I'm not so sure.

- result.entries has results.
- fieldname has data as well, so these two things are not the problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because [`queryEntities`](http://azure.github.io/azure-storage-node/TableService.html#queryEntities__anchor) is an async function, and `res.end()` executes before the for-loop ends. In this case, I'd recommend looking at [async module](https://github.com/caolan/async) and using `async.eachOf(...)`. It allows you to run async calls against a list of 'things' and gives you a place to run a function when all of the async calls are done.

```
var async = require('async');

// ...

async.eachOf(modelEntries, function(value, key, next) {

    if (result.entries[key].fielddatatype._ === "Enum") {
        enumName = result.entries[key].fieldname._;
        query = new storage.TableQuery().where('EnumName eq ?', enumName);

        storageClient.queryEntities(enumvalue, query, null, function (error, result, response) {
            enumList[enumName] = result.entries;
            next();
        });     
    }

}, function(err) {

    res.end(JSON.stringify(enumList));

});
```